# How to use remote user authentication using simple-jwt with Jwk Url in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, microservices, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, remoteusermiddleware

I have two django projects/microservices which uses two **separate** databases:

1. Todo auth - built for authentication - **todo auth database**
2. Todo project - built to view todo information specific to a user - **todo database**

What I basically require is,

Once a user login using the todo auth project and get a token,

When using the token in the todo project, the user should be authenticated and created (if the user does not exist) in the **todo database** with the help of Remote user authentication.

I only want to use simple-jwt **with jwk url** to achieve this.

Is this possible? Please let me know how I can achieve this. Many thanks.

PS: I'm running the two projects/microservices separately in the same development server on two different ports